# Optimize time charging a page (request with Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, eloquent

I would like to optimize my code in order that the page takes less seconds charging.

In every pages, I have a handle function that makes requests to mysql DTB, and I would like to know if it would be possible to stock some of the datas for the day, and eventually update the datas one time a day or when a certain function is called. I must precize that I use Eloquent to make requests.

Is that possible?

EDIT : Here is the code I called everytime a page is charged

```
$handleMenu = function () use ($app){
return function() use ($app){
    $req = $app->request;

    //Get resource URI
    $resourceUri = $req->getResourceUri();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["Edition"])) {
        $_SESSION["Edition"] = "NANCY";
    }
    $selectedEdition = Edition::where("nomXML", "=", $_SESSION["Edition"])->first();
    $rubriques = Rubrique::where("nomAssocie", "!=", "Edito")->where("nomAssocie", "!=", "Offre d'emploi")->get();
    $saisons = Article::with("rubrique")->where("saison", "=", true)->take(5)->get();
    $festival = Article::with("rubrique")->where("festival", "=", true)->take(5)->get();
    $editions = Edition::where("nomAssocie", "not like", "%-%")
        ->where("nomXML", "!=", "TTES EDITIONS")
        ->where("nomXML", "!=", "ARTGASTRONOMIE")
        ->get();
    $today = $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $banniere = Pub::where("type", "=", 2)
        ->whereHas("Pub_Edition", function($query) use($selectedEdition){
            $query->where("id_edition", "like", "%".$selectedEdition->id_edition."%");
        })->where("date_deb", "<=", $today)
        ->where("date_fin", ">=", $today)
        ->orderByRaw("RAND()");
    if(strpos($resourceUri, "/articles/rubrique/") !== false){
        $arr = explode( '/', $resourceUri );
        $banniere = $banniere->whereHas("Pub_Rubrique", function($q) use($arr){
            $q->whereHas("Rubrique", function($q2) use($arr){
                $q2->where("nomXML", "=", $arr[3]);
            });
        });
    };
    $banniere = $banniere->first();
    if($banniere != null){
        $banniere->nb_affichage = $banniere->nb_affichage + 1;
        $banniere->save();
    }
    $twig = $GLOBALS["globalapp"]->view()->getEnvironment();
    $twig->addGlobal('menuRubriques', $rubriques);
    $rubriques = $rubriques->toArray();
    usort($rubriques, function($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a["nomAssocie"], $b["nomAssocie"]);
    });
    $twig->addGlobal("rubriques", $rubriques);
    $twig->addGlobal("festivals", $festival);
    $twig->addGlobal("saisons", $saisons);
    $twig->addGlobal("editions", $editions);
    $twig->addGlobal("actualEdition", $_SESSION["Edition"]);
    $twig->addGlobal("selectedEdition", $selectedEdition);
    $twig->addGlobal("banniere", $banniere);
};
};
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the SQL statements?  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most DBMS's are pretty good at caching queries so that's probably not the bottle neck. You need to make sure the query itself is optimised. If you're using Eloquent, make sure any relations are [eager loaded](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). If not done, that's what will often slow down your page loads, as you're making a lot of trips to the DB.
If really necessary you could use an object cache like Memcached or Redis to cache your data, but as said, MySQL is pretty good at caching queries...

Comment: thanks a lot ! I already eagger loaded all queries that are related, but all of them are not related.

Comment: As there is no code example it's hard to establish what you are trying to do, but caching your query results to an object cache could be done, as long you make sure that the cache gets invalidated correctly when data changes. Another strategy is to use an HTTP cache like Varnish, so the request doesn't even hit your application... but that really depends on what the application is.

Comment: ok sorry I will give you some precision : I have a website, and the menu is buit with elements from a database, with multiple tables. Not all elements are related, and the function is called in every page with a handler (called by the framework Slim defore charging view). I'll edit my post

Comment: I think using an object cache like memcached is your best bet here... You can then cache the data that's not likely to change and use the day's date as a cache key... Looks like you're randomising the ordering though, so you might want to not include that in your cache. Where the query is dependant on dynamic SESSION data it shouldn't be cached either. And then you just need to make sure you invalidate the cache when data changes.